# Vertical Background Color

Tags: html, css

**Problem :**
I want to make this background color vertical instead it shows as a block

[image: Current Image]

What I want to do is make this background color vertical for the whole screen and make the paragraphs (other texts) show beside them with a little gap

My code:
{HTML}

```
<main>


    <div class="nm">

        <h1 class="intro__1">

           <span class="nm__1">Team</span>
           <span class="nm__2">Eros</span>

        </h1>

       
       

    </div>  
    <div class="intro">

        <p class="who">

            <strong>

                ㅤㅤ >❓ Who we are

            </strong>

            <p>
                ㅤㅤ //  Eros is a team of MineCrafters<br>
                ㅤㅤ //  who play together and do the impossibles<br>
                ㅤㅤ //  that no one has ever seen done before.
           </p>
         


   </div>
    <p class="who__2">
        ㅤㅤ  >  Our Journey
    </p>
    <p class="who__3">
        ㅤㅤ We started on the server, Bedcraft. <br>
        ㅤㅤ Bedcraft is a bangladeshi minecraft <br>
        ㅤㅤ server with minigames like bedwars  <br>
        ㅤㅤ and It also has survival with <br>
        ㅤㅤ  interesting twists. <br>
    </p>
 </p>


</main>
```

{CSS}

```
/* Main Channel */

.nm{
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 130px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;


  opacity: 0;
  animation: down 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.nm:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40vw;
  background-color: rgba(126, 126, 126, 0.178);
  backdrop-filter: blur(11px);
}
span.nm__1{
  font-family: 'Righteous';
  font-size: 140px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: rgb(180, 200, 255);
  white-space: nowrap;

  opacity: 0;
  animation: down 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

span.nm__2{
  font-family: 'Righteous';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 128px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: url(Images/download.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(Images/download.png);
  mask-image: url(Images/download.png);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;

  opacity: 0;
  animation: down 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.intro{
  margin-left: 180px;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  
  opacity: 0;
  animation: down 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* About */

p.who{
  margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
  
  opacity: 0;
  animation: down 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
p{
   margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;  
   font-size: 20px;
   color: white;

   opacity: 0;
   animation: down 3.5s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
p.who__2{
  margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(221, 220, 220);

  opacity: 0;
  animation: down 3.5s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

**What I want to do:**
[image: Goal]
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'background color vertical', also which background color?

Comment: The one behind the text "Team Eros"